# Read/write arrays declared in appdelegate in my viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, uitableview, class, nsmutablearray

I have 4 NSMutableArrays declared in my AppDelegate header file, because I need populate them from a file, if file is non nil in the application did finish launching method. I can do that part OK, but I need to use those arrays in 2 view controllers in my storyboard. (There NSMutableArray s are to populate tableviews. How do I make all the classes be able to read/write to these arrays?

Comment: Simply access your app delegate from the view controllers. Then you can access those array properties.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property for the two array's in your view controllers and pass the arrays where you create the view controllers. This way you do not have to change your view controllers when you decide to move to arrays into a different class (as the AppDelegate is likely the wrong place to store these anyway).